# Using Url.Content in ASP.net MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've seen a lot of examples using Url.Content to reference javascript, form MasterPages in MVC 2.

```
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But on runtime I've got failure,

> Compilation Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context.

I haven't find where Url namespace is declared, should additional assemblies be using?

VS2010, IIS 7, ASP.net MVC 2.0

Comment: If you take out that line, does your app run properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your master page inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage

Answer (score 2):

alex,

try adding the following extension method and see if it get's you any further

```
public static partial class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string Script(this HtmlHelper html, string path)
    {
        var filePath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(path);
        HttpContextBase context = html.ViewContext.HttpContext;
        // don't add the file if it's already there
        if (context.Items.Contains(filePath))
            return "";
        return "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" + filePath + "\"></script>";
    }
}
```

usage:

```
<%=Html.Script("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js")%>
```

I know it won't answer your question directly, but will allow you to move fwd...

Comment: jim, thanks! this is actually acceptable.. but I would try to find out why Url.Content just doesn't exist??? I'm googling now, could not find a documenation for it.. maybe it is really gone?

Answer (score 1):

Removed edit, as single quotes get treated as character literal, so causes 'too many characters in literal' error.  The most likely cause is still a typo, IMHO.

ORIGINAL POST (still stands re the UrlHelper class):

Url.Content():  Url here is a helper method, a bit like the Html or Ajax helpers.

In code, I believe its class is:

System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper

Ie, the namespace is System.Web.Mvc.

So it is very odd that you can't just use it if, that is, you really are using the spec you detailed above.

Comment: Seriously.. there is no System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper assembly, there is no such namespace.

Comment: I didn't say there was.  I said there is a class called UrlHelper in the System.Web.Mvc namespace.

Comment: Just another error: CS1012: Too many characters in character literal, in the same line.. So strange.. (

Comment: Sorry!  It is wrong to have single quotes with Url.Content.  see the following SO thread:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629920/where-is-this-too-many-characters-in-string-literal-message-coming-from