# Updating relative locations in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a file structure that looks like the following:

```
/root
  /images
    image1.png
    image2.png
    button1.png
    button2.png
  /css
    app.css
    core.css
  /scripts
    jquery-1.6.4.min.js
    jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js
  /path1
    /pathA
      index.cshtml
      page1.cshtml
    index.cshtml
  /path2
    /pathA
      index.cshtml
      page1.cshtml
    /pathB
      index.cshtml
      page1.cshtml
    index.cshtml
  index.cshtml
  _layout.cshtml
```

All of the .cshtml files rely on _layout.cshtml for the shared content. My _layout.cshtml file looks like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/core.css" />    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css" />

    <script src="/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #button1 .ui-icon { background: url(/images/button1.png) }
        #button2 .ui-icon { background: url(/images/button2.png)  }     
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

This file references all urls by starting with "/". Unfortunately, this won't work when I move my app to PhoneGap. I was hoping to replace all beginning "/" with a relative path. For instance, if I accessed /path1/pathA/index.cshtml I would want the two button css definitions to look like:

```
  #button1 .ui-icon { background: url(../../images/button1.png) }
  #button2 .ui-icon { background: url(../../images/button2.png)  }
```

Is there a way that I can automatically change my paths so that they are relative like shown above? Am I making sense in what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you use the built in html helpers, for example:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

...

```
#button1 .ui-icon { background: url(@Url.Content("~/Content/images/button1.png")) }
```

Comment: How do I reference Url.Content? When I try, I get an runtime error that says: "CS0103: The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context". I saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912508/using-url-content-in-asp-net-mvc-2-0 but I don't know how to inherit something in _Layout.cshtml. Ugh.

Comment: what version of mvc are you using? I don't think you need to inherit something in a razor view, that was for mvc2 with webform views

Comment: can you upload your project files somewhere? or send them by email? to see if i can help you better